# java.net.ConnectException when running MPJBOOT on linux cluster

Tags: java, linux, mpi, connectexception, mpj-express

I followed the steps on page http://mpjexpress.org/docs/guides/linuxguide.pdf, and I can start daemons on all machines. If I just run program on single server, it runs successfully

`[ip1,master] MPJ Daemon started successfully with process id: xxx`

`[ip2,node] MPJ Daemon started successfully with process id: xxx`

But when I use command `mpjrun.sh -np 2 -dev niodev HelloWorld`, it shows `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` and `Multi-threaded starter: exceptionnull`, but I can **Ping** this IP successfully.

Is anything wrong? Thanks for your comments.

Comment: connection refused means, target machine is up and running but the port you are trying to connect is not lsitening.  first reason your daemon is not running target machine or this may happen because of firewalls, check the target machine firewall configuration.

Comment: I face the same problem.. I have turned off firewall, antivirus, etc.. but it always refuses the connection.. have you solved this problem?

Comment: No, I didn't solve this problem, but I changed the version of MPJ(0.43). It can run successfully now.